# How access struct elements inside pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following schema for a pyspark dataframe

```
root
 |-- maindata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- unit: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- dateTime: string (nullable = true)
```

Giving some data for a particular row which I received by `df.select(F.col("maindata")).show(1,False)`

```
|[[[a1, 43.24, km/h, 2019-04-06T13:02:08.020], [TripCount, 135, , 2019-04-06T13:02:08.790],["t2", 0, , 2019-04-06T13:02:08.040], [t4, 0, , 2019-04-06T13:02:08.050], [t09, 0, , 2019-04-06T13:02:08.050], [t3, 1, , 2019-04-06T13:02:08.050], [t7, 0, , 2019-04-06T13:02:08.050],[TripCount, ,136, 2019-04-06T13:02:08.790]]
```

I want access the tripcount value inside this ex: `[TripCount -> 136,135 etc`,What is the best way to access this data?TripC is present multiple times
and also is there any way to access say for example only label data like maindata.label..?

Comment: can you post sample data and reproducible code

Comment: @ShubhamJain have added some sample data. Can you please check.. Basically I need to fetch all the values for tripcount..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to do `explode` multiple times, to convert array elements into individual rows, and then either convert struct into individual columns, or work with nested elements using the dot syntax. For example:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode
df=spark.createDataFrame([[[[('k1','v1', 'v2')]]]], ['d'])
df2 = df.select(explode(col('d')).alias('d')).select(explode(col('d')).alias('d'))
>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _3: string (nullable = true)
>>> df2.filter(col("data._1") == "k1").show()
+------------+
|        data|
+------------+
|[k1, v1, v2]|
+------------+
```

or you can extract members of the struct as individual columns:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode
df = spark.createDataFrame([[[[('k1','v1', 'v2')]]]], ['d'])
df2 = df.select(explode(col('d')).alias('d')).select(explode(col('d')).alias('d')).select("d.*").drop("d")
>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _3: string (nullable = true)

>>> df2.filter(col("_1") == "k1").show()
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
| k1| v1| v2|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: the statement `df=spark.createDataFrame([[[[('k1','v1', 'v2')]]]], ['d'])` gave me error: `_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: The above issue was coming with Python 3.11.2. It disappeared after using Python 3.8.10.